# Wordpress. Contact Form 7. Отправка email'a юзера в виде текста

Tags: php, wordpress, email, contact-form7

Возможно ли как-то отправить email, который ввёл пользователь в виде текста, а не в виде ссылки? Подозрения на то, что некоторые почтовики не пропускают email ссылкой и просто не отображают его.

Comment: Он и так отправляется в виде текста.

Comment: В шаблоне письма убрать теги <a></a> вокруг email

Comment: @SeVlad но на почту приходит в виде <a href="mailto:">

Comment: @Behmetev шаблон отправляет email в виде шорткода [email]. Я не могу управлять структурой шорткода, это надо лезть во внутренности плагина

Comment: Нет, на почту приходит ровно то что ты отправляешь. Это КЛИЕНТЫ преобразуют в ссылки. Ты вообще не тем занимаешься. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710

Comment: @SeVlad Я рад, что ты занимаешься именно "тем". Это логично, что клиент преобразовывает полученную информацию так, как ему удобно. Вопрос в том, как отправлять данные из CF7, чтобы КЛИЕНТ отображал ссылки.

Comment: @РомаХр ты бы, прежде чем пытаться хамить, сходил бы по ссылке.